# Get the length/number of colums in the current line/row

Tags: vimscript

How can I get the length of the current row in vim script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current line you can use [`:h getline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29) giving it the parameter `'.'`. This will return a string, all you have to do next is to get the length of this string, to do so you have several options: [`:h string-functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#string-functions)

```
strlen()        length of a string in bytes
strchars()      length of a string in characters
strwidth()      size of string when displayed
strdisplaywidth()   size of string when displayed, deals with tabs
```

So your code could be:

```
let size = strwidth(getline('.'))
```

Comment: Using `col('$')` is also possible...

Comment: @filbranden If I remember correctly `col('$')` will report N+1 for a line containing N characters since it reports the position of the cursor when it is after the last character of the line. Depending on what you want to do it could be problematic, and as OP didn't specified what they want to do I decided not to include it in my answer. But you are right it is another possibility.